# Add a custom header property in JWT assertion for OAuth

Tags: oauth, jwt

How do I add additional header properties to my JWT using the **JWTBearerTokenExchange** Class?
(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_JWTBearerTokenExchange.htm#apex_class_Auth_JWTBearerTokenExchange)

The token I need to sign requires a an additional property "kid" (Key ID) but I don't think there is a method to add this?

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

`kid(Key ID)` is a custom claim, you can add your custom claim to the JWT using .[setAdditionalClaims](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_JWT.htm#apex_Auth_JWT_setAdditionalClaims) . JWT Claims are basically Key-value pairs like Map, so you have to create a map and provide your values. Here your `kid` is a [private-claim](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token)

```
        Auth.JWT jwt = new Auth.JWT();
        jwt.setSub('user@salesforce.com'); 
        jwt.setAud('https://login.salesforce.com'); 
        jwt.setIss('3MVG99OxTyEMCQ3gNp2PjkqeZKxnmAiG1xV4oHh9AKL_rSK.BoSVPGZHQ​ukXnVjzRgSuQqGn75NL7yfkQcyy7');

        //Additional claims to set scope
        Map<String, Object> claims = new Map<String, Object>();
        claims.put('kid', 'myKeyId');

        jwt.setAdditionalClaims(claims);

        //Create the object that signs the JWT bearer token
        Auth.JWS jws = new Auth.JWS(jwt, 'CertFromCertKeyManagement');

        //Get the resulting JWS in case debugging is required
        String token = jws.getCompactSerialization();

        //Set the token endpoint that the JWT bearer token is posted to
        String tokenEndpoint = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';

        //POST the JWT bearer token
        Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange bearer = new Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange(tokenEndpoint, jws);

        //Get the access token
        String accessToken = bearer.getAccessToken();
```

Comment: kid is an optional header. I know we can use setAdditionalClaims for additional claims but there doesn't seem to be a method to add a header.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to put the kid in the payload. Is there any way to put it in the header?