# Manually set or change header properties in JWT

Tags: integration, authentication, jwt

I am running into an issue in developing for JWT Server -> Server workflow.

I can use the [JWT class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_JWT.htm) to set properties in the Payload of the JWT with methods like setSub, setAud etc.

However, when I use this JWT in creating a [JWS object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_JWS.htm#apex_class_Auth_JWS), the attributes in the JWT header are automatically set by the system and are seemingly not modifiable.

So if I do something like:

```
Auth.JWS jws = new Auth.JWS(jwt,'some_cert_name');
```

I get a JWT with a header properties of:

```
{ "typ": "JWT", "kid": "some_cert_name", "alg": "someHashAlg" }
```

Is there any possible way to modify the "kid" property here? Salesforce has a restriction where I can not upload a .jks with certain characters (in this case, a '-'). I receive an error message when I attempt to upload my JKS file (Criteria for valid keystore alias here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387657&type=1):

```
Error: Keystore contains an entry whose alias is not acceptable for import: some-cert-name
```

The server that is validating our JWT expects a kid that contains the '-' character like so:

```
{... "kid":"some-cert-name" ...}
```

I'm a bit stuck here as my JWT auth will fail with the auth server, as we cannot provide the correct kid that has been registered on their end. Is there any way to resolve this and provide the correct kid without changing some value on the auth server?

Thanks so much for your help

**Note:** [I found this older question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249782/add-a-custom-header-property-in-jwt-assertion-for-oauth) which is roughly asking the same as I am, but the answer ignores the question entirely which is changing the property in the header.

Comment: Via `Auth` namespace - no. You can rename the alias in JKS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483121/how-to-change-the-alias-of-a-key-within-a-keystore

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @identigral but in the question i mention we are required to submit the kid with a '-' which is taken from the alias. Salesforce will not allow us to load a jks file that has an alias with this character.

Comment: Limitations on alias names that you can upload to salesforce: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387657&type=1

Comment: `kid` is arbitrary, you should be able to change it on the other end. But if you can't do that, then you have to construct the JWT yourself and sign it yourself. There are some Q&As here with code, e.g. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13301/connect-apex-and-google-api-using-jwt-to-retrieve-oauth-2-0-token

Comment: @identigral I had the same impression as well, but the authentication team I am working with have stated the incorrect kid value is the explicit issue with our jwt being invalid.

In the linked question you provided it looks good - however, the private key is exposed in the apex class in plain text. I don't think that would be acceptable for my employer's security standards, which is why i was hoping it could be managed via JKS file.

Is there a recommended pattern to do this more "securely" or am i out of options

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_storing_sensitive_data.htm describes the options